# Ethernet does not work after connecting graphics cards

Tags: networking, graphics-card, ethernet

I have put together a machine with a motherboard running Ubuntu, and a PCIe-plugged graphics card.

Before connecting the graphics card, the machine was able to connect to the internet via the ethernet cable. I was able to successfully run `ping` and `ssh` into the machine from my laptop.

However, after connecting my graphics card, the machine now fails to connect to the internet. The ethernet cable is plugged in same as before, but now `ping` fails with an 'unknown host' error, and I am unable to ssh to the machine as before.

**How could simply connecting a graphics card stop my machine from connecting to the internet?**

I am wondering what I can try to get my machine internet-connected with the card plugged in.

---

Additional information:

**Monitor signal output only through card when card is connected**.
Before running into this trouble with the ethernet not connecting, I faced some trouble with connecting the monitor. If I plugged the monitor to the board without the card connected, then signal would be sent to the monitor and the monitor would successfully display. However, with the card connected, monitor signal was not sent from the board and the monitor would only display when connected directly to the card.

**Machine only detects card's presence when card is plugged in at startup**.
The machine appears to only detect the card's presence at startup. If I connect the card after the machine has started, the machine behaves as if the card is not connected (`lspci` does not show the card, internet works and monitor can display connected to board). If I connect the card before startup, the machine does notice the card (`lspci` shows the card's presence, internet does not work, and monitor only displays when connected to the card).

---

When the card is plugged in and the machine does not connect to the internet, the output of `ifconfig` is

[image: screenshot output of <code>ifconfig</code> with card plugged in and ethernet does not work]

---

Output of `lspci` when card is plugged in and machine does not connect to the internet is[image]

---

Output of `ifconfig eth0 up` when card is plugged in:

[image]

Comment: Did you remove the card to confirm it was the cause?

Comment: @Paul my machine only detects the card's presence if the card is connected at startup, and, if I disconnect the card after startup then I cannot see the output of any commands. The question has been edited to show further detail on these points.

Comment: First of all, most systems do NOT have hot-plug PCI-e. Please do not plug in a card unless the computer is fully off.   Secondly: Output from the graphics cards plugs is normal. Unless you have a very weird setup (or a laptop) this is normal. Onboard graphics uses the onboard outputs. Regular graphics cards use their own output.

Comment: Ok, having said that, Paul has a good question. Remove the graphics card. Try again. Write down your network information for good measure (including DNS information). Power down, reinsert graphics cards, power up and check your boot logs. Any conflicts? Any changes in network configuration? Etc.

Comment: What does ifconfig show when you can't connect?

Comment: @Tim_Stewart question has been edited to include a screenshot of `ifconfig`'s output when card is plugged in and ethernet does not connect.

Comment: the one reason I can think of is the pcie lanes are switched between the ethernet adaptor and the card, but that makes zero sense. Does the NIC turn up in say lshw or lspci when the video card is plugged in?

Comment: @JourneymanGeek the word 'NIC' is not shown in the output of `lspci` when card is plugged in. Question has been edited to show that output.

Comment: ya, you have a working ethernet controller - starting to smell a little like a very strange software issue

Comment: IIRC there are some issues with the RTL8111 driver; it's probably some driver problem unrelated to the graphics card, and pure chance that it stopped working when you did something to the card.

Comment: Very odd. What happens when you do a manual down/up using "ifconfig eth0 up" ?

Comment: @Tim_Stewart `$ ifconfig eth0 up` gives output `eth0: ERROR while getting interface flags: No such device`. (Question has been edited to show this.)

Comment: What kernel version are you using?  uname -r or uname -a    As of today 6.5.5 is the newest.

Answer (score 8):

I know this is from a long time ago - but I just had this same thing happen to me so I figured I'd let you know what the issue was for me.  When I added a graphics card my machine would boot, but I couldn't ssh into it, but the normal screen would show up.  The issue was my ethernet interface name would change when the graphics card was plugged in.  Normally it was a enp5..., but when I put in the new graphics card, it became enp6..., so the interface reference in my netplan file wouldn't work.  I just had to change my netplan yaml file from enp5 to enp6, apply, and it worked fine.

Comment: Thank you so much for pointing this out! Saved me a lot of time and trouble.

Answer (score 0):

I case this may help someone, I've been moving video cards around between two computers and noticed twice that when I made a change, my ethernet adapter stopped working. I had to pull out the video cards and fire up the computer without them once and then put them back in again and all was fine.

Answer (score 0):

As found in [*From The Desktop* section here](https://www.redhat.com/sysadmin/network-interface-linux), I accessed the Networking icon at the top right in Gnome on the desktop.  It showed `Wired Off`, I simply turned it on and the Ethernet card woke up (`Wired Connected`), got its DCHP address, and we were reconnected to the network with a different name on the interface.

In this installation, the interface names followed Rule 3 has listed [here](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/8/html-single/configuring_and_managing_networking/index),

> Device names incorporate the physical location of the connector of the hardware. If this information is not available or applicable, udev uses scheme 5.

Before I found this solution I was headed down that rabbit hole of dreaded manual configuration and overrides.  The hidden magic of the desktop setting restored the renamed Ethernet interface. After reading up on the details of Linux interface naming policy when confronted with new hardware in the slots, it would have been nice to see script, but (UI) beggars can't be choosers.

This all happened on RHEL 8 on an AMD Ryzen Aorus Elite EX motherboard where I supplemented on-board graphics with a PCIe graphics card (RX 6000).